# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined when trying to use .get() with .all()

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a REST API signature like so:

```
http://www.example.com/hierarchies/nodes/1005/parents
```

It responds in a nested format as below:

```
{
    name: "",
    children: [
        {
            name: "",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "",
                    children: [
                        ..
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to call the API like so:

```
var service = Restangular.all('hierarchies');

return service.one('nodes', id).all('parents').get();
```

But it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

(Note: I am able to receive the response with `.getList()` but with Restangular "Error: Response for `getList` SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else" which I can fix by changing the API to return the data in list format.)

Is it a must to always use `.getList()` with `.all()`? Is it wrong to use `.get()` with `.all()`?
Is there some way I can make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restangular - How do I reach this API using GET method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738289/restangular-how-do-i-reach-this-api-using-get-method)