# Restangular - How do I reach this API using GET method?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How do I make a GET call to a REST API with the below signature:

```
http://www.example.com/hierarchies/nodes/1005/parents
```

I am trying to call the API like so:

```
var service = Restangular.all('hierarchies');

return service.one('nodes', id).all('parents').get();
```

But it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

The API call(if successful) would respond in a nested format as below:

```
{
    name: "",
    children: [
        {
            name: "",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "",
                    children: [
                        ..
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think if you use `all` as the last part of the builder, a list is expected and you should use `getList` instead of `get`. However the object you are expecting does not look like a list, so you could change the last part of your builder to just use `one` without the second parameter and then a single object as the response will be expected.

```
service.one('nodes', 5).one('parents').get().then(function(response) {
});
```